# SRTP on Asterisk

Tags: security, ssl, asterisk

I set up a GNS3 topology with Asterisk and 2 softphones (Blink) and i tried to enable secure calls.(https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial)
TLS  works, SRTP don't work .

In my Asterisk (last version), SRTP module is enable and running (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3kgN.jpg). Pjsip.endpoint.conf have "media_encryption = sdes" in GUI looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Avyp.jpg.
The the softphones configuration is this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6PvL.jpg

```
[100]
type=endpoint
aors=100
auth=100-auth
tos_audio=ef
tos_video=af41
cos_audio=5
cos_video=4
allow=ulaw,alaw,gsm,g726,g722
context=from-internal
callerid=CEO <100>
dtmf_mode=rfc4733
transport=0.0.0.0-tls
aggregate_mwi=yes
use_avpf=no
rtcp_mux=no
ice_support=no
media_use_received_transport=no
trust_id_inbound=yes
media_encryption=sdes
timers=yes
media_encryption_optimistic=no
send_pai=yes
rtp_symmetric=yes
rewrite_contact=yes
force_rport=yes
language=en
```

What seems strange to me is that although encryption is SDES mandatory, I can make calls, even if traffic is UDP.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP9tF.jpg It looks as if the settings in the asterisk match the ones on the softphone, but the traffic is not encrypted.

Where am I wrong? What am I missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SRTP is function of endpoint.

So ALL your endpoints SHOULD support SRTP.

Comment: Yes, all endpoint support SRTP, they have the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the answer.
In wireshark I enable RTP over UDP (rtp_udp) and now i see RTP trafic instead of UDP. When i  listen the call is only noise, so is encrypted, but why wireshark don't show me SRTP traffic?